# Nuxt 3 middleware infinite navigation guard

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, middleware, nuxtjs3, nuxt-middleware

I've created auth.global.ts

Detected a possibly infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/auth/login" to "/34/create-issue". Aborting to avoid a Stack Overflow.
Are you always returning a new location within a navigation guard? That would lead to this error. Only return when redirecting or aborting, that should fix this. This might break in production if not fixed.

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    let authStore = useAuthStore()
    let { isLoggedIn } = authStore
    const token = useCookie('token')

    if (to.name == 'id-create-issue' && from.name !== 'id-create-issue') {
        return navigateTo(to.path, { replace: true })
    }

    if (isLoggedIn && to.path === '/auth/login') {
        return navigateTo('/company')
     }

     if (!token.value && to.path !== '/auth/login') {
        return navigateTo('/auth/login', { replace: true })
     }

}
```

Comment: Possibly this `if (to.name == 'id-create-issue' && from.name !== 'id-create-issue') {}` condition makes an infinite navigation. Can you share the `id-create-issue` page script?

Comment: create-issue page is just a form nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (to.name == 'id-create-issue' && to.path !== from.path) {
    if(from.path !== to.path) {return}
    return navigateTo(to.path, { replace: false });
}
```

Check `from.path` and `to.path`; if they are the same, then return nothing. This will prevent an infinite loop.

You can also disable middleware for this specific route by:

```
if (to.name == 'id-create-issue') {
     return;
}
```

Comment: disable middleware helped me a lot that's what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `to.name` instead `from.name` like this 
<s>if (to.name == 'id-create-issue' && from.name !== 'id-create-issue') {}</s> 
`if (to.name !== 'id-create-issue') {}`

as indicated in [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#format).

Comment: here the route is dynamic and if I do if (to.name !== 'id-create-issue') {} it never enter to the if condition

Comment: Did you try this? Route name will be the same even if it is dynamic. Can you share folder structure?

Comment: pages/[id]/create-issue

and middleware/auth.global.ts
if (to.name == 'id-create-issue' && from.name !== 'id-create-issue') {
        return navigateTo(to.path, { replace: true })
    }